# get android phone smsc number programmatically

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to get the SMS center number (smsc) of a phone programmatically in android. Is that possible ? I have tried searching but couldn't find anything?

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out!,
 But here are the steps: 
0. Allow these permissions in the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

1. Create a broadcast receiver service
2. You will receive the SMS onReceive in pdu format, then you will need to convert it to SMSMessage.

The SMSMessage has a bunch of properties and methods, one of them is 
getServiceCenterAddress() which Returns the address of the SMS service center that relayed this message or null if there is none.

```
  public class SMSProcessor extends BroadcastReceiver {
// handle the onReceive 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle smsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";
        clientSMS = new ClientSMS();
        if (smsBundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) smsBundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String format = smsBundle.getString("format");
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
                } else {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }

            clientSMS.setSmsc_originating_message(messages[i].getServiceCenterAddress());


  }
   // do stuff with the smsc aka value of getServiceCenterAddress()
}
```

Don't forget to register the Service in the Manifest file too

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".controllers.SMSProcessor"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Note: the export = true in order to listen for system wide services
and we set high priority for good reasons.

Comment: What about the user and password, is there a way to get them?

Comment: which password and user? can you be specific

Comment: I can connect to an SMSC server using its ip, user and password, using this project for example: https://github.com/delhee/SimpleSMSTransmitter.git . Or maybe I got it wrong?

Comment: that's something different from the question asked, above. The question was how to get SMSC id/phone for incoming SMS in android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in the android documentation and use the getServiceCenterAdress() method.
(android.telephony.SmsMessage)